# Does sneezing repeatedly lead to orgasm, or a similar sensation?

Tags: physiology, sexuality

This came up randomly during office talk but it goes something as follows; sneezing repeatedly is equivalent to having an orgasm.

Some [basic](http://www.snopes.com/science/stats/sneeze.asp) [research](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110716024431AAwJO8K) [on](http://www.amirite.com/129201-if-a-sneeze-is-the-equivalent-of-one-eighth-of-an-orgasm-what-happens-if-you-sneeze-eight-times-in) [the](http://blog.lib.umn.edu/vanm0049/myblog/2011/10/sneezing-is-orgasmic.html) [internet](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Is_sneezing_one_eighth_of_an_orgasm?#slide=1) seems to indicate there is some basis behind this statement with many people stating things like "10 sneezes is equivalent to 1/10th of an orgasm" or "8 sneezes is like an orgasm" while other sites [cite this as a myth](http://www.livescience.com/34337-sneezing-like-orgasm.html) or incorrectly understood statement.

Since I'm not going to sit here forcing myself to sneeze repeatedly to test it out for myself I was wondering - is there any actual fact behind this?

Is it true that sneezing repeatedly is equivalent in any way to an orgasm?

Comment: I think what the question is getting at is that the same neurotransmitters are released in the brain, which would not be that surprising, but which is kind of a pointless statement. If this is the case, see my reply here, exact details may vary but the main point is the same: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18799/does-a-dogs-brain-secrete-the-same-substances-when-it-sees-its-owner-as-humans

Comment: But the opposite seems to be true: [Sneezing induced by sexual ideation or orgasm: an under-reported phenomenon](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2625373/).

Comment: I have _allergies_. In allergy seasons I sneeze  >150 times per hour for the whole day (minus sleeping hours), often in quick successions of 8-15 sneezes. That's thousands of sneezes a day. I assure you, **it feels nothing like an orgasm** (no orgasm I know of, at least). My abs get really stiff, though.